# Git incorrectly recognising a newly added file as copy of an existing file

Tags: git, bitbucket

Git seems to consider a few newly added files in the repository as copies, and it messes up the diff shown in the PR on bitbucket (as it now shows a fully new file as a changed diff of an existing file).

The git diff command shows it correctly as a new file.

```
diff --git a/conf/CMakeLists.txt b/conf/CMakeLists.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000000..950acb62bd
--- /dev/null
+++ b/conf/CMakeLists.txt
@@ -0,0 +1,43 @@
+#
+# 
+#
<snipped>
```

But git log --find-copies-harder --name-status

shows the status as

```
C070    libs/cpr/CMakeLists.txt conf/CMakeLists.txt
```

Which is what seems to cause the bitbucket server to show this file as a diff against another existing file.
[image]

Is there a way to avoid this so that the file shows up as a new file, which it actually is?

Comment: Perhaps do not use `--find-copies-harder`?

Comment: Its automatically being used by the bitbucket. I suppose I need to look at the bitbucket configuration.